# How can i move those red tiles at the end of the disk in order to make a partition? Windows-11

Tags: partitioning, windows-11

See the [tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYne8.png) here.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You would need to move the partition contents to an external disk, shrink the partition and copy the data back.

Comment: You can try defragmenting, which is easy and safe, but there's no guarantee it will free space at end. However, it looks like that might be a small disk, with insufficient free space - not enough info to tell.

Comment: What software is that? What have you tried? If this is an SSD, fragmentation isn't a thing and those boxes are not an accurate representation of the real arrangement of data on your drive or the viability of creating additional partitions. If this is an HDD, a defrag would help move the available space to the end of the existing partition allowing creating a new partition.